# Null check for string in java

Tags: java

When `a=null` and `b=null` it throws `NPE`.

```
String a,b;

if ((aValue.equals("null")||aValue==null||aValue.isEmpty()) && 
(!bValue.equals("null")||bValue!=null || !bValue.isEmpty()))
```

I want to check when a has no value and b has value.
How to make it proper and efficient without any libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aValue==null` must be checked first, since the expression is evaluated from left to right and `aValue.equals("null")` would throw a `NullPointerException` if `aValue==null`.

The checks for `bValue` should have `&&` (AND) condition between them, since you require `bValue` to have a value. Again, `bValue!=null` should be evaluated first.

```
if ((aValue==null||aValue.equals("null")||aValue.isEmpty()) && 
(bValue!=null && !bValue.equals("null") && !bValue.isEmpty()))
```

BTW, do you expect `aValue` or `bValue` to ever contain the `String` "null"? Would such value represent "no value"? If that's not the case, the tests of `.equals("null")` are not necessary.

Comment: True, `avalue.equals("null")` checks for String equality in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Eran.. a and b could be any value.I am checking your code in my framework.

Comment: Hi @Eran still It throws NPE because of bvalue.any other suggestions ??

Comment: @thanga Did you notice that I also changed the conditions for `bValue`? I checked the code and it doesn't throw NPE.

Comment: Can you please explain why you added && ?? how it makes difference ?

Comment: @thanga You require bValue to have a value, so it should be `!= null` AND `!equals("null")` AND `!isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

first u have to check `aValue==null` because if it has `null` then at `aValue.equals("null")` it will throw an exception ie null pointer exception.to avoid that you should use

```
if ((aValue==null||aValue.equals("null")||aValue.isEmpty()) && 
(bValue!=null && bValue.equals("null") && !bValue.isEmpty()))
```